# why is ng-repeat not working in custom directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to AngularJS and I cannot get `ng-repeat` to work when embedded in a directive as follows

```
<settings-widget>
    <ul class="ul-border">
     <li class="box" ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</settings-widget>
```

```
app.directive("settingsWidget", function ($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: "true",
        scope: { },
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: "/Settings.html",
        compile: function (element, attrs, transclude) {
            return function (scope) {
                transclude(scope, function (clone) {
                    var html = angular.element("<div>").append(clone).html();
                    scope.template = html;
                });
            };
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $rootScope) {
            $scope.list = ['item1', 'item2'];
        }]
    };
});
```

Settings.html

```
<div>
        <form id="settingsForm" name="settingsForm" novalidate ng-submit="save(settingsForm)" ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true}">
            <div compile="{{template}}"></div>
        </form>
</div>
```

for some reason when I run my app `<li>` tags are not being created.

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Try using `replace: true` instead of `replace: "true"`

Comment: @SudhirOjha no luck

Answer (score 0):

**1. Normal transclusion (passed html uses parent scope):**
**You define `list` in parent controller!**

```
<settings-widget>
    <ul class="ul-border">
     <li class="box" ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</settings-widget>

app.directive("settingsWidget", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: "true",
        scope: { },
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: "/Settings.html"
    }
});

<div>
        <form id="settingsForm" name="settingsForm" novalidate ng-submit="save(settingsForm)" ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true}">
            <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
        </form>
</div>
```

**2. No transclusion (passed html uses directive scope):**

```
<settings-widget additional-tpl="'myTemplate'">
</settings-widget>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate">
    <ul class="ul-border">
     <li class="box" ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</script>

app.directive("settingsWidget", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: { 
          additionalTpl: '<'
        },
        templateUrl: "./settings.html",
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.list = ['item1', 'item2'];
        }]
    };
});

<div>
        <form id="settingsForm" name="settingsForm" novalidate ng-submit="save(settingsForm)" ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true}">
            <div ng-include="additionalTpl">
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

**2. Transclusion+ (passed html want to use both directive and parent scopes):**
This one seems to be tricky and I never actually did that, I guess quite easy way is using `$parent` ref cause you dont have this `compile` manual calls:

```
<settings-widget>
    <div>By default I take value from parent scope {{parentCtrlValue}} 
    </div>
    <ul class="ul-border">
       <li class="box" ng-repeat="item in $parent.list">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</settings-widget>

app.directive("settingsWidget", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: { },
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: "./settings.html",
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.list = ['item1', 'item2'];
        }]
    };
});

<div>
    <form id="settingsForm" name="settingsForm" novalidate ng-submit="save(settingsForm)" ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true}">
        <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
    </form>
</div>
```